# Joining 2 flexible plastic tubes

Tags: plumbing, pipe, connectors

I discovered a small puddle on my basement floor yesterday. I have a pump that moves condensation from my boiler to a drain. It runs for a second or two every few hours.

The piping is clear, flexible tubing and I found two sections disconnected. Based on the small clamps I'm guessing there was a connector between the two, but I can't find it.

I went to the hardware store and bought a slightly larger tube to connect these two, and clamped it in place.

Unfortunately, the larger tube didn't hold.

My question is whether my approach of using a wider tube should have worked. (Maybe I just need to tighten the clamps?) Or it is better to find a narrower tube and place it inside the two I want to join? Or is there an even better way I should be approaching it?

[image]

Comment: Check the drain hose for obstructions. There should not be enough pressure building up to cause the hose to blow apart when clamped in place.

Answer (score 13):

The correct way to fix this is with a barbed hose coupler fitting that looks something like this:

[image]

<sup>*[Picture Source](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07SN46ZBX)*</sup>

You want to get the size that will fit snugly inside the existing plastic / vinyl tubing. These barbed couplers are available in brass and several types of plastic depending upon application specifics. With the proper fit and tubing that is not hard and brittle you may not even need to use hose clamps over the ends of the tubing for low pressure applications such as yours. Clamps can help to keep it from pulling apart if you desire.

Comment: It appears that this is exactly the type of barbed hose coupling that is still in the ends of the tubing and that the connector itself simply broke (which strikes me as rather unusual). The old pieces of connector will have to be pulled out of the ends of the tubing. At this point, it might just be easier to replace the entire run with a new piece of tubing that doesn't need a splice in the middle. Even with COVID tax, a few feet of tubing isn't expensive.

Comment: @FreeMan I agree. Difficult to tell from the photo but it looks indeed like the halves of a broken coupler are still in there. Warm the tubes a bit to make the plastic more malleable and pull them out with pliers. As I discovered a few years ago you can break one of these couplers (or create a hairline crack that breaks later) by over-tightening those jubilee clamps.

Comment: Boiler condensate is acidic (mostly due to carbonic acid), and will corrode common metal fittings including copper and brass.  That is probably why the old one failed, and is why you should not use the fitting pictured. Use a plastic one. Otherwise this answer is spot on.

Comment: @JackB - I modified the answer slightly to indicate various types of materials and applications.

Answer (score 1):

You should get a tube of the same diameter and connectors that are suitable for that tube (type and size).  The clamps will only work if the joining tube is a very snug fit over the existing tube.

Answer (score 1):

Obtain a length of plastic tubing of the same i.d. as the o.d. of the copper. Loosen the clips, slide them along the copper. Boil some water and put it into a small container. Put the ends of the plastic into that hot water, and when it's supple, force it over both coppers. May be easier one end at a time. make sure the plastic goes over at least an inch but you may need to cut off the brass joint that's failed in order to do all this. Leave the plastic so it's a flexible joint - not under stress. Tighten the two clamps, job done.

IF they're not copper, as they appear, then do the opposite! Obtain a length of copper, same o.d. as the pipes are i.d., and follow instructions, but this time, the two pipes will clamp onto the copper!

Or - as Mike suggests, leave the broken stubs in, and use a plastic pipe which encompasses them, and tighten the clamps onto those bits left inside. That gives something which won't collapse easily.

Comment: Arguably it would be better to leave the broken bits of connector in there - if jubilee clips are needed, they will make the connector more secure. Many plastic tubing systems have such pieces as standard, to add rigidity to the ends.

Comment: @MikeB - good point, I'll add it in. Thanks.